# How to create a String to convert numbers into words

Tags: string, numbers, words, poker

I'm having trouble creating a String that will allow my numbers in a 5 Hand Poker Assignment turn into words. The numbers are from 1 to 52, represent each card in the deck. Ace of Spades in 1, 2 of Spades is 2... 14 is Ace of Clubs... 27 is Ace of Diamonds... and 40 is Ace of Hearts, etc. I want to print out the number to their according card. What is the code for this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: What programming language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Define an array/list

   cards=["Ace of Spade",
          "Two of Spade,
         ...
         ]

2.Create string

```
String = cards[number]
```

3 Do it again for all cards and print result